# JQuery .validate() in IE not working

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer

I have a website that validates the input fields before a user is allowed to submit.  Everything was working fine until I recently made a change that broke the site for IE.  I will give an example of what my code looked like before.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myFormId").formValidate();
    //other stuff

});

JQuery.fn.formValidate = function() {

    var myForm = this;

    $(myForm).validate({
      //validation code is here
    });

    $("#exampleInputField").rules("add", {
      required: true,
      alphaNumeric: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 15
      });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
      "alphaNumeric",
      function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
      },
      "Only alphanumeric characters are valid."
      );
}
```

I declared my validation function outside of the document ready function, and I call formValidate() on the form when all of the elements are loaded.

This code was able to run in IE and FF perfectly fine.  Then, I added some functionality to the code for saving the form.  For validations on saving, I don't want to have a 'required' field, but I still want to check if the input fields have valid inputs.  I kept the validation function the same, only making the change in the `$(document).ready()` function, shown here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myFormId").formValidate();

    $("#saveButton").click(function() {
      $("#myFormId input").each(function() { $(this).rules('remove', 'required');});
      //This removes the 'required' field from each input's rule set, but still keeps the other rules
    });
    //other stuff

});
```

After this change, my code does not work in IE anymore, but it works fine in FF.  When I try to save in IE, I get a script error with the debugger turned on, saying `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'rules'` for `$(this).rules('remove', 'required');});`.  I even tried to call `$("#myForm").valid()` in the console, and it says the form does not support the property or method 'valid' or 'validate'.  It seems to me that the validation is not being called, or the validate library isn't getting loaded properly, but I did not make any changes to that.  Does anyone know what is going on?

Update: So, I also have it set up when a user clicks the submit button, I revert back to the original validations by just calling it again by using `$("#myFormId").formValidate();`.  When they click the submit button, I get a warning again, but it appears that it **is** performing the validations as it is supposed to.  So, to give a better idea, this is what it looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myFormId").formValidate();

    $("#saveButton").click(function() {
      $("#myFormId input").each(function() { $(this).rules('remove', 'required');});
      //This removes the 'required' field from each input's rule set, but still keeps the other rules
    });

    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
       $("#myFormId").formValidate(); //same as before, but debugger complains about 
                                      //this specifically
    });

    //other stuff

});
```

**Another Update:** So whenever I call `$("#myFormId").formValidate();` in the document.ready function, I'm not getting an error from IE.  However, anytime I call it from the console, or inside another event, it says the form does not support it.  Could calling it a second time cause errors?

Comment: To give an update as well, whenever I open the dev tools to investigate it, it completely crashes my browser, until I have to close the inspection tool.

Comment: The error you are getting doesn't make sense... that kind of error should be happening in all browsers, unless you're having a caching or mime-type issue.

Comment: @KevinB that's why I'm so confused, haha.  I actually found out that, when hitting the submit button in IE, it does the original validations just fine, but it still shows me a debugger error.  And my html page has `no-cache` specified.